# Encrypt Web.Config Programmatically in Global.asax

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, encryption

I would like to check and then programmatically encrypt my web.config during the Application_Start (global.asax) if its not already encrypted.

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    EncryptConfig.Encrypt("/Web.config");
}
```

And My Method

```
protected internal static void Encrypt(string applicationPath)
{
    private const string Provider = "RSAProtectedConfigurationProvider";
    private const string Section = "connectionStrings";

    var test = applicationPath;

    var confg = WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration(applicationPath);
    var confStrSect = confg.GetSection(Section);

    if (confStrSect != null)
    {
        confStrSect.SectionInformation.ProtectSection(Provider);
        //confStrSect.SectionInformation.ForceSave = true;
        //confg.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified);
        confg.Save();
    }
}
```

I am getting the following exception which im having no luck resolving using Google and StackOverflow

An exception of type 'System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException' occurred in System.Configuration.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: A configuration file cannot be created for the requested Configuration object.

Comment: instead of passing the path, let the app find it. var confg = WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("~");

Comment: Thanks that's fixed it

Comment: Great solution - thanks for posting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Dbugger mentioned in the comments the solution is

```
WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("~"); –  dbugger
```

Comment: Great solution - thanks for posting.  Did you go for that method in the end?

Comment: It worked but as I was in Azure i moved all the config to the Azure Web Config so noting sensitive left in that file.